# Not able to communicate ping through scapy using global address while using multiple network cards

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ipv6, scapy, bgp

I am using 3 network cards on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. I am trying to simultaneously communicate to 3 different networks using three different network cards. I want to use IPv6 Global addresses.
Below is the network structure.

`Interface_A (8003::2) <-----> Get0 (8003::1)`
`Interface_B (8001::2) <-----> Get1 (8001::1)`
`Interface_C (8002::2) <-----> Get2 (8002::1)`

When I work with IPv6 link layer addresses, simultaneous communication is working. i.e. below code is working successfully.

```
dst_a="FE80::C1:4160" # get0
dst_c="FE80::3617:EBFF:FEAE:DEB4" # get2
src_a="FE80::3617:EBFF:FEAE:DEB5" # my_pc_interfac_A 
src_c="FE80::523E:AAFF:FE08:8AAF" # my_pc_interface_C
IFACE_A = "eth0"
IFACE_C = "eth2"
echo_a = IPv6(src=src_a, dst=dst_a, nh=58) / ICMPv6EchoRequest(data='aaaa')
echo_c = IPv6(src=src_c, dst=dst_c, nh=58) / ICMPv6EchoRequest(data='cccc')

conf.iface = IFACE_A
a = sr1(echo_a)
a.display()

conf.iface = IFACE_C
c = sr1(echo_C)
c.display()
```

While below code is not working, only 1st ping is successful (echo_a). For the next one I am not getting any response. When I am working with only interface_C (echo_c) with global ipv6 addresses, echo_c is also working.

```
dst_a_global="8003::1" # get0
dst_c_global="8002::1" # get2
src_a_global="8003::2" # my_pc_interfac_A 
src_c_global="8002::2" # my_pc_interface_C
IFACE_A = "eth0"
IFACE_C = "eth2"
echo_a = IPv6(src=src_a_global, dst=dst_a_global, nh=58) / ICMPv6EchoRequest(data='aaaa')
echo_c = IPv6(src=src_c_global, dst=dst_c_global, nh=58) / ICMPv6EchoRequest(data='cccc')

conf.iface = IFACE_A
a = sr1(echo_a)
a.display()

conf.iface = IFACE_C
c = sr1(echo_C)
c.display()
```

I am getting only echo_a output, for echo_c there is no response.
If I run echo_c first, I am not getting response for echo_a.

I expect that, for both the echo request there should be an echo reply. I am able to ping6 on all the interfaces.

Comment: Did you sniff the interfaces using Wireshark to check which packet is sent in which interface? maybe edit your question with this information

Comment: I am using wireshark, for each interface, and I am able to see that, both the packets are traveling through correct interface only.

Comment: It doesn't make so much sense. If you are doing everything in the same way, and same packets are sent, each on the correct interface, there is no reason there will be a difference. Are you sure they are sent in the correct interface in all cases? is there any other difference between the sniffed packets?

Comment: Yes, It is not making sense to me also :( This is the scenario. Requests are being sent correctly, I am struggling with this. :(

Comment: Do you see the Ping responses in Wireshark for both requests? (meaning- is it a problem with scapy that doesn't read them right, or the other side doesn't answer)

Comment: I don't see any ping response (only for multiple interface, Ipv6 global add) in wireshark, when I am using scapy to send packets. But when I am pinging through CLI it's working.

Comment: and no difference between the packets from the CLI and Scapy? take a look carefully, there should be some difference, maybe in the addresses

Comment: No difference except data field, which can't be responsible for such behavior.

Comment: can you post some images? of the ip protocol fields on the packet that get a response specifically?

Comment: Please, never use invalid IPv6 addresses. If you do not have Global IPv6 addresses, then use ULA addresses. Also, you do not detail what mask length you are using.

Comment: Prefix length is 64. Does it make any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure also the Ethernet layer yourself and see if it is working-

```
echo_a = Ether(src=YOUR_MAC, dst=33:33:00:01:00:03) / IPv6(src=src_a_global, dst=dst_a_global, nh=58) / ICMPv6EchoRequest(data='aaaa')
a = srp1(echo_a, iface=IFACE_A)
```

Also- I had some problems myself using IPv6 with multiple interfaces (using regular socket instead of Scapy, and Windows), take a look to see if you can find something relevant (I couldn't think of anything particular, but maybe it will help anyway)-

- [Windows doesn't receive multicast IPv6 packets from all interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280816/windows-doesnt-receive-multicast-ipv6-packets-from-all-interfaces)
- [Sending IPv6 multicast packets through a specific network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077323/sending-ipv6-multicast-packets-through-a-specific-network-interface)

Comment: HI Shir, I already tried srp1 method. The situation is same. I think there may be some problem with system ethernet layer.